# How to use the :first-of-type rule inside a styled-components/emotion partial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I'm trying to replicate some CSS in Emotion using [Partials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516893/6025788) but I don't see how it's possible to replicate a rule like `:first-of-type` in a situation where I'm using a `partial`. Is there some way to achieve this?

**Starting CSS:**

```css
li.item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
}

li.item.isResult:first-of-type {
  background: pink; /* Don't know how to port this rule */
}
```

**Best attempt at porting this rule to Emotion:**

```js
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { css } from '@emotion/core';

const Item = styled.li`
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  ${resultPartial}
`

const resultPartial = props => props.isResult && css`
  &:first-of-type {
    background: pink; // Has no effect
  }
`
```

PS: Although `partial`s don't seem to be mentioned in Emotion's docs, they are supported and do work. I'm specifically wondering about how to go about recreating a `:first-of-type` rule inside a partial.

Answer (score 5):

Not a solution, but an explanation why it doesn't work.

```js
const Div = styled.div`
  color: black;
  &:first-of-type {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Generates CSS like this:

```css
.HaSh{color: black}
.HaSh:first-of-type{color: red}
```

However, the CSS spec only allows "type" to be a tag name for `first/nth/last/only-of-type`. Yet, `styled-components` relies and must rely on class names to distinguish differently styled `div`'s. Thus, a dead end.

I believe you can work around the limitation (in general) by setting the style on any "parent's child", e.g.:

```js
const Comp = () => <Container><p>1</p><p>2</p></Container>;

const Container = styled.div`
  & > *:first-of-type {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```